# Limit_choices_to via Q

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get a list of data from my foreign key related field but it doesn't work with limit_choices_to

my model

```py
def limit_choices_segment():
    return Q(role=Place.CITY) & Q(role=Place.VILLAGE) & Q(role=Place.TOWN)


class Segment(CoreModel):
    start_point = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=limit_choices_segment,
                                    related_name='departing_point')
    end_point = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=limit_choices_segment,
                                  related_name='arriving_point')
    routes = models.ForeignKey(Routes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.start_point, self.end_point)
```

when i tried it only with single Q(role=Place.CITY) or another it works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to do

```
def limit_choices_segment():
    return Q(role=Place.CITY)  Q(role=Place.VILLAGE) | Q(role=Place.TOWN)
```

instead? It might not be working because you're using `&` for three different roles which filters them all.

Comment: but | means "OR", I need to include all this filters, so that's why I should use & "AND"

Comment: `or` includes them all, while `and` will only include objects whose role is all those three things at once, which logically does not match any object.